# Trying to understand Diophantine equations.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm revising for an upcoming exam and do not understand how you solve these questions at all. It all seems like a bit of trial and error to get any type of solution. The questions I am looking at are:

(i) Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. What are the possible values of $x^{4}+x^{2} \mod8$?

(ii) Let $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. What are the possible values of $y^{4}+5 \mod8$?

(iii) Find all solutions (if any) of the Diophantine equation $x^{4} + x^{2} = y^{4} + 5.$

I'm not even sure where to start so any help and insight in to these equations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "It all seems like a bit of trial and error" yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that: $$x^n\equiv(x+8)^n\mbox{ (mod 8)}$$

This means that we only have to test from $0$ to $7$ to have the complete set of possible remainders.

For example, we would like to know what the possible remainders of $x^2$ are:

$$\begin{matrix}
0^2&\equiv&0&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
1^2&\equiv&1&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
2^2&\equiv&4&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
3^2&\equiv&1&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
4^2&\equiv&0&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
5^2&\equiv&1&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
6^2&\equiv&4&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
7^2&\equiv&1&\mbox{ (mod 8)}\\
\end{matrix}$$

Therefore, the possible remainders are $\{0,1,4\}$.

Now you may continue your attempt.

Comment: so for (i) i get the solutions to $x^{4}+x^{2}$ mod 8 as 0,2,4. for (ii) i get the remainders as 5,6.
Does this mean for (iii) as 0,2,4 $\neq$ 5,6 there are no solutions to $x^{4}+x^{2}=y^{4}+5$?

Comment: @LVI Yes, that is correct (sorry for the late reply).